# Not able to print correct output for first two strings in the array for wordbreak problem

Tags: java, string, dynamic-programming

**Problem Statement:**
Given an input string and an array of N words, find out if the input string can be segmented into a space-separated sequence of dictionary words.

**Input**

10

i like sam sung mobile ice cream man go mango

ilike

**Output**
true

I am able to code the problem and the problem seems to work perfectly fine for input-**samsung/icecream** but when inputting **ilike** I am getting false. I guess I am doing something wrong while inputting the dictionary in array .pls help. Here is my code for your reference.

```
public class wordbreak {
    
    static Set<String> dictionary=new HashSet<>();
    public static boolean check(String str,int[] arr)
    {
        int n=str.length();
        if(n==0)
            return true;
        if(arr[n]==-1)
        {
            arr[n]=0;
            for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
            {
                String part=str.substring(0,i);
                if(dictionary.contains(part) && check(str.substring(i),arr))
                {
                    arr[n]=1;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return arr[n]==1;
    }
     public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        String dict[]=new String [n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            dict[i]=sc.nextLine();
        }
        for(String i:dict)
        {
            dictionary.add(i);
        }
        String str=sc.nextLine();
        int arr[]=new int[str.length()+1];
        Arrays.fill(arr, -1);
        System.out.println(check(str,arr));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if i run this, the result ist true.
But unfortunately this is always checking the last dictionary String, mango in this case.
That's because `sc.nextInt()` does not read the newLine-Character.
This newLine-Character is consumed by the first `sc.nextLine()`, resulting in a shift for the inputs.
If you **debug this** you will see that dict[0] is "".
To resolve it you need a extra `sc.newLine()` after the `sc.nextInt()`.

Comment: Thanks @frank.Issue got resolved by adding sc.nextLine()